# how to download a pdf after opening a link using python (not using selenium)

Tags: python, html, pdf, python-requests

After opening link in browser, we will have an option as PDF, if we click on PDF, present page will be downloaded as PDF format. Here, we want to download multiple file in PDF using Python. How to do it? Here PDF option in link is define as class with Href.

Comment: Hello, post what you've tried and a code example please.

Comment: Yes, please share what you've done, and what exact output do you expect.

Comment: 'import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://link' # mention link of webpage
webbrowser.register('chrome',
 None,
 webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
 #webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Internet Explorer//iexplore.exe"))
x=webbrowser.get('chrome').open(url)  ## Opening the Webpage

print(x)

## after this i want to download PDF of this current page'